# Empty() function doesn't work in OOP

Tags: php

I have this code where I try to check if $name is empty. In procedural style works everything great but in OOP seems that the empty function doesn't work. I'm not very experienced in PHP so please explain where is the problem and how to fix this.

```
 <?php
    // The code below creates the class
    class Check {
        // Creating some properties (variables tied to an object)
        public $name;
        public $subject;

        // Assigning the values
        public function __construct($name, $subject) {
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->subject=$subject;
        }

        // Creating a method (function tied to an object)
        public function checking() {
         if (empty($name)) {
            echo "empty name";
         }
         else {
            echo "name set";
         }
        }
      }

    $me = new Check('Mark','somesubject');
    echo $me->checking();
    ?>
```

Comment: It's an object property, not a locally scoped variable, so `if (empty($this->name)) {`

Comment: read about [`$this`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use :

```
if (empty($this->name)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
 if (empty($this->name)) {
    echo "empty name";
 }
 else {
     echo "name set";
  }
```

Because you are using OOPs concept here in the code. When you need to refer variable of the same class then you need to use `$this->` keyword followed by 
class's variable name that is declared inside the constructor as

```
 public function __construct($name, $subject) {
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->subject=$subject;
        }
```